# UIButton Image Align issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I got CheckBox Image which is top on UIButton with text.I have problem Align the text to Left and Image to Right. what were the width of UIButton, the Text Should be Align to left and Image Should be Align to Right. i have tried may Answer. but i did't get text exact. please help me.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* checkBoxBtn;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat LableHeight = 40;
    self.checkBoxBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.checkBoxBtn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 150, LableHeight);
    self.checkBoxBtn.center = self.view.center;
    self.checkBoxBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.checkBoxBtn setTitle:@"Alert Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkBoxBtn setImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxUnChecked"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(LableHeight, LableHeight)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkBoxBtn setImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxChecked"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(LableHeight, LableHeight)] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    self.checkBoxBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    self.checkBoxBtn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:self.checkBoxBtn];

    [self.checkBoxBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxBtnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)checkBoxBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender
{

    BOOL isSelected = sender.selected;
    if (isSelected) {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your question; try this to inverse button state: `[sender setSelected:![sender isSelected]]`

Comment: iam not trying to inverse the button state, iam trying to set text to left and image to right.

Comment: it will be good if you can post an image of end result that you want.